# Finding HTTP_REFERER empty/blank when using URL shortener site

Tags: php, http, browser, http-headers

I have a client who is trying to determine traffic metrics, to his site by way of those "URL shortened" sites: (tinyurl.com, bit.ly and x.co) to be specific, and to take action based on that traffic...

We would have thought that the HTTP_REFERER variable would have held the referring resource name, the shortened URL from that service.   Instead the HTTP_REFERER field is empty and if read in some browsers its actually not even there (I guess NULL?).

Here is an example of an attempt to enter a shortened URL that goes to my client's site and the name of the page is x.php:

```
HTTP_CONNECTION:keep-alive HTTP_KEEP_ALIVE:115 HTTP_ACCEPT:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,application/json HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip,deflate HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-us,en;q=0.5 HTTP_COOKIE:ASPSESSIONDQADBDABT=HAEFPIOBONKMOIJFDGNHHEM HTTP_HOST:www.<myclientswebsite>.com HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 (.NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
```

Why wouldnt the http://x.co shortened URL show up in the header info OR am I not looking in the correct place?

My client would ultimately like to redirect incoming traffic to the appropriate resource within his website AND/OR out to other sites he owns.

**UPDATE:** I've looked through his raw traffic logs and I cant find a specific referrer other than x.co or bit.ly, etc   I do not see the "/" part..  Is there something I can change in his IIS6 settings, on his web server, that would allow us to see and utilize the information he's looking for, or are we just out of luck due to the design of the HTTP redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the shortening services use response `301` or `302` and `Location` - there is no referer. Your browser does not pass it.

Comment: Can you think of any way around the fact that the browser doesnt send it or am I needing to tell the client to forget what he wants to achieve?

Comment: the browsers (the ones i've tested) do not send the header. it is fact. and you should decide what to do then ;-)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP_REFERER is an optional header. In some cases they are stripped out (security software, proxies, etc).

In the case of URL shortening services, they probably do a header redirect and simply don't include HTTP_REFERER.

Comment: "they probably do a header redirect and simply don't include HTTP_REFERER. " --- you're completely wrong, it is user's browser sending the referer header, not the shortening service.

Comment: @zerkms: Are you saying that its possible to retrieve this information or are the browsers just not coded to do such and that is the way its going to be?

Comment: i don't know how do they coded, also - i don't remember any http rfc mandatory about not to send referer when it is 30x response, i just interprete behaviour of modern browsers.